# HQL: DISTINCT Issue

Tags: sql, hql, hive

Say I have a table of Customer, Vendor the Customer visited, with each row being a distinct time a certain customer visited a vendor.

```
Row  |  Customer  |  Vendor  
1    |  1         |   001        
2    |  1         |   001
3    |  1         |   002   
4    |  2         |   001
```

My question is, how can i pull a query to show every distinct visit to a certain vendor. For the above table, I'd like to see output of:

```
Row  |  Customer  |  Vendor  
1    |  1         |   001        
2    |  1         |   002   
3    |  2         |   001
```

Comment: You should just be able to apply a DISTINCT to the select of the two columns. e.g.
SELECT DISTINCT Customer, Vendor FROM table_name

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `DISTINCT` clause, assuming that the **row** column is just for illustration purpose here, and not part of the actual table

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer, vendor
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by`:

```
select min(row) as row, Customer, Vendor
from table t
group by Customer, Vendor;
```